# TimeMachine setup backup to internal harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine

I want to setup TimeMachine backup to my internal hard-drive on MacBookPro with Mojave 10.14.3
(I know it is not safe in case the hard-drive fails!)

So I added a new encrypted AFPS volume. But in TimeMachine setup I can not select it.
Can I do this? (without losing all my current data on my internal drive)

Comment: If I remember correctly, TimeMachine can only use an HFS+/Journaled HFS+ drive, and will format any partition your target drive as such